# How do I change the color of a certain part of my image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, vector

So basically, I want to edit my image (which was designed by a close friend of mine) to change my glasses from white color, to black instead. I've tried editing the hue/saturation but failed to achieve the effect.

[image: this is the image ...]

I want to learn how to do it in Photoshop. Your kind advice would be greatly appreciated :) Still relatively new to the program and learning.

Much thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I grabbed a screen shot of your image, and then pulled it into Photoshop. By using the wand with a tolerance of 32 I was able to select nearly all of the white. I then created a new layer above the image, and painted within the selection I just made so you had a new layer of black for the glasses. I then added a stroke to that layer (to help cover any missed single pixel white spots) and adjusted the stroke to be 1px, black, multiply, and 80%. I came out with this result:

[image]

It isn't 100% perfect, but it isn't bad considering it was less than 5 minutes of effort.

Answer (score 0):

First, looks great.
Second, It probably wont be as easy as a filter, you will probably need to do a little bit of manual editing.

A couple ways to do it might be, and im sure there are plenty more.

1. Using the pencile/paintbrush to draw over it in black, on another layer, and set the ocupancy to like 75, so it bleeds the other layers through.
2. Use the selection tool/ magic wand and select the white, then do the hue filter like you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The most automated, non-destructive way of doing this that I can think of is to:

1. First limit your selection to roughly around the glasses like I did with this marquee selection.
2. Then goto Select > Colour Range
3. Add and remove colours from the selection with the dropper tools. (You should only need to select the white of the glasses in this instance)

[image: Colour Range]

4. With your new selection create an adjustment layer, I used Hue Saturation but you could use a few others and achieve the same effect.

[image: Fill and Adjustment layer]

5. If you aren't happy with the result you can add or subtract from the layer mask in a variety of ways including:

   - "Refining the Edge" which can be access from right clicking the mask in the layers panel.
   - Expanding or contracting the selection
   - or more simply by painting values directly on to the mask layer.

[image: Final Result]